# Pure Javascript mouseenter and mouseleave event delegation with React issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I would like to achieve something like this on my React project (https://creativesfeed.com/code/custom-cursors/index2.html)

I want to have a custom mouse cursor (a dot in this case which is in a "div") which follows the coordinates the mouse and that's fine, I can make it work.

The other thing that I want to achieve is that when hovering on ANY  tag, a custom class will be added to the custom mouse cursor and removed when the custom cursor leave the link. The problem is that whenever I hover on the  tag, the class appear and disappear immediately. I know that eventListener in Javascript are different from jQuery and I even tried with jQuery (which I hate to have in React) and I have the same issue. So what am I doing wrong? Could it be because I run the function on componentDidMount() ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let mouse__follower = document.getElementById('mouse__follower');
    let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      var x = e.clientX;
      var y = e.clientY;
      mouse__follower.style.top = `${y}px`;
      mouse__follower.style.left = `${x}px`;
    });

    let addClassToLink = (e) => {
      mouse__follower.classList.add('active');
    };

    let removeClassToLink = (e) => {
      mouse__follower.classList.remove('active');
    };

    // ALSO, IS THIS VERY BAD IN TERMS OF MEMORY CONSUMING?

    for(var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
      links[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', addClassToLink, false);
      links[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', removeClassToLink, false);
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nu-creative">
        <div id="mouse__follower">
          <div id="mouse__follower__circle"></div>
        </div>
        <Homepage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The link is in another file, but I think that's not the issue.

**EDIT:** I have found the issue. If I remove

```
mouse__follower.style.top = `${y}px`;
mouse__follower.style.left = `${x}px`;
```

from the `document.addEventListener("mousemove", ...)` the class is added and removed correctly, so there's must something there that I can do. Maybe is because two eventListener are triggered together.

I will investigate, thanks for the answers so far :)

Comment: my guess is whatever you are adding is the culprit. Is it going under the cursor when you add the class?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the react life cycle is messing around with you. The thing is that react re-renders the html whenever it decides it should be done, and in your render method you are removing the inline classes.

So, the way to do this react-wise would be to set a flag in the state of your component which you change with `setState`, and check for this flag in your render method to decide wether or not add the class to the cursor.

Something like this:
`<div id="mouse__follower" className={this.state.cursorActive? "active":""}>`

**Edit**:
btw, this is not related but, remember to unbind all your event listeners that were bound in `componentDidMount` inside the `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 0):

ISSUES SOLVED :)

The z-index of the div containing the "dot" wasn't set and this was causing the event to trigger too many times. By setting the "z-index" to -1 the issues was solved.